# Text with overflow dind't resize to fit his container

Tags: flutter

I want to create a row with image and text. TextOverflow.visible didn't work even if I use expanded with flex widget. Can you help me?
Here is my code

```
SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
              resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
              body: CustomScrollView(
                slivers: [
                  SliverFillRemaining(
                    hasScrollBody: false,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                            child: Row(children: [
                              ConstrainedBox(
                                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                      maxWidth:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                              0.4,
                                      maxHeight:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                              0.4),
                                  child: const Image(image: emptySearch)),
                              Row(children: [
                                Text("U - lo Músico?",
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                                    style: Theme.of(context)
                                        .textTheme
                                        .displayLarge)
                              ])
                            ])),
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
                          child: Form(...))
```

Answer (score 0):

**i'm try to solve your problem :**

> Use Expanded inside the Row Widget

```
Row(children: [
  Expanded(
    child: Text(
      "U - lo Músico?",
      overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
      maxLines: null,
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge,
    ),
  ),
]),
```

Answer (score 0):

Thaks for the efford! I've already solve it, just have to change `Row(children:[Text...])` for `Expanded (child: Text...)`